# avoid mouse events on one div that is below another

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to achieve the effect of "flip card". in the front, I have an element that has a click event, every time you click on it (.link). In the back there is nothing, but when I pass the cursor where the element with the .link class that is in the front, the click event is executed.

[image]

I would like to completely isolate the elements from the front part of the ones in the back part. how can I do it?

```
<div class="scene scene--card">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card__face card__face--front">
      <a class="front_button link">
          text
      </a>     

    </div>
    <div class="card__face card__face--back">
      back
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>

.scene {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  margin: 40px 0;
  perspective: 600px;
}

.card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: transform 1s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  position: relative;
}

.card.is-flipped {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card__face {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 260px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 40px;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.card__face--front {
  background: red;
}

.card__face--back {
  background: blue;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.front_button{
  background:yellow;
  height:200px;
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0px;
  left:0px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.link{
 border:1px solid red; 
}

var card = document.querySelector('.card');
card.addEventListener( 'click', function() {
  card.classList.toggle('is-flipped');
});


var link = document.querySelector('.link');
 link.addEventListener( 'click', function() {
 alert("link");
});
```

this is my code:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pOWONW

testing code from @Temani user 
[image]

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation

Comment: @TemaniAfif can you please be a little clearer, this would also disable the events that you have on the back of my card, if I had them ..

Comment: @TemaniAfif I just want to avoid having interaction with the opposite side.

Comment: like this: https://jsfiddle.net/8qtmnvro/ ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif same problem...

Comment: in the code I provided both element are isolated, no? can you be more clear .. and what browser are you using, am testing with FF and Chrome

Comment: @TemaniAfif Look at the image that I uploaded, corresponds to your code, my problem has not been solved. I would ask you to please open my question again, since you yourself can see that this solution does not work for me. I'm trying with Google Chrome.

Comment: you issue doesn't happen for me ... don't know how you are able to trigger this effect it's probably a bug

Comment: I see the issue in chrome.  Set pointer events to none on the link when the card has the class `is-flipped`.

Comment: If setting `pointer-events: none` is too much (e.g.: perhaps you want other events / links to work on the backside), you could alter your link eventhandler to check if parent card.is-flipped. If so, do nothing

Comment: @Geert-Jan with this css class my problem is solved, but I would have another one. I can no longer flip my card


.card.is-flipped {
   transform: rotateY (180deg);
   pointer-events: none;
}

Comment: @yavg you misunderstand.  Set pointer events none on the actual link not on the card.

Comment: @StevenB. I do not understand you. If I put this property on the text, then it will never work. I need it to work when it's on the front, and it does not work when it's on the back.

Comment: .link.is-flipped {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  pointer-events: none;
} not works for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the pointer events from the link when the card has the class `is-flipped`.

```
.card.is-flipped .front_button.link {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```js
var card = document.querySelector('.card');
card.addEventListener( 'click', function() {
  card.classList.toggle('is-flipped');
});


var link = document.querySelector('.link');
link.addEventListener( 'click', function(e) {
e.stopPropagation();
 alert("link");
});
```

```css
body { font-family: sans-serif; }

.scene {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  margin: 40px 0;
  perspective: 600px;
}

.card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: transform 1s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  position: relative;
}

.card.is-flipped {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card.is-flipped .front_button.link {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.card__face {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 260px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 40px;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.card__face--front {
  background: red;
}

.card__face--back {
  background: blue;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.front_button{
  background:yellow;
  height:200px;
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0px;
  left:0px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.link{
 border:1px solid red; 
}
```

```html
<div class="scene scene--card">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card__face card__face--front">
      <a class="front_button link">
          text
      </a>     
    </div>
    <div class="card__face card__face--back">
      back
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<p>Click card to flip.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "pointer-events" (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) in your css for the is-flipped class.

```
.card.is-flipped {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

This makes it ignore all mouse events.

Comment: thanks, with this css class my problem is solved, but I would have another one. I can no longer flip my card